# Why is my input delayed when sent to process via pipes?

Tags: c, audio, pipe, ipc

I'm writing a program for an operating systems project which is meant to basically be a modem keyboard as in I type a key and it outputs an FSK-modulated-audio-signal corresponding to the ASCII value of that key. How I've set up my program is that it forks a process and execs a program called minimodem ([see here](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/) for info). The parent is set to non canonical input mode and gets user input a character at a time. Each character is then sent to the child via a pipe. I'll just paste the code now:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

extern char* program_invocation_short_name;

static struct termios old, new;
void init_termios(int echo);
void reset_termios(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
pid_t pid;
int my_pipe[2];

char* baud = "300";
if (argc == 2) {
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 0) {
        printf("Use: %s [baud]\n",program_invocation_short_name);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    baud = argv[1];
}

if (argc > 2) {
    printf("Too many arguments.\nUsage: %s [baud]\n",program_invocation_short_name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

if (pipe(my_pipe) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s",program_invocation_short_name,strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

pid = fork();
if (pid < (pid_t) 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s",program_invocation_short_name,strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}else if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
    /***************/
    /*CHILD PROCESS*/
    /***************/
    close(my_pipe[1]); /*Child doesn't write*/
    dup2(my_pipe[0], 0); /*Redirect stdin to read side of pipe*/
    close(my_pipe[0]); /*Close read end as it's dup'd*/
    execl("/usr/local/bin/minimodem","minimodem","--tx", baud,"-q","-A",NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s",program_invocation_short_name,strerror(errno));
}else if (pid > (pid_t) 0) {
    /****************/
    /*PARENT PROCESS*/
    /****************/
    char c;
    close(my_pipe[0]); /*Parent doesn't read*/
    init_termios(1);
    atexit(reset_termios);

    while(1) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 0x03)
            break;
        if (write(my_pipe[1], &c, 1) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s",
                    program_invocation_short_name, strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    close(my_pipe[1]);
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void init_termios(int echo)
{
    tcgetattr(0, &old); /*get old terminal i/o settings*/
    new = old; /*make new  settings same as old settings */
    new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /*set appropriate echo mode*/
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /*use new terminal i/o settings*/
}

void reset_termios(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}
```

My problem is with the user input. When typing it seems that the first character gets written and audio is generated then there's a delay then the rest of the characters in the buffer get generated continuously like they're meant to. If there's a big enough pause in the typing then it's back to the start where the first character typed after the break gets generated followed by a delay and then the intended functionality.
I have my fingers crossed that this isn't because the minimodem program wasn't written to be used in this way and that this problem can be overcome.
If anyone can shed some light on the matter I would be sooo greatful.
Thanks.

NOTE: I've tried putting the input into a ring buffer and then that input being consumed and sent to the child in a seperate thread. NOOOT better. Not even sure if noting this was productive.

Comment: I see in the source code for minimodem that it explicitly writes 0.5 seconds of silence whenever there is not enough data to keep the audio buffer full.  Is that the amount of delay you are hearing?

Comment: Yes! I would say that's the amount of time. What file and line did you see this on? What do you think the reasoning behind adding that silence is? Could you give me a hint on how to get around this? I have no qualms with altering and recompiling minimodem.

Comment: I've written up an answer that hopefully explains the situation.  Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimodem will write 0.5 seconds of silence when it detects that there isn't enough input data to keep the audio buffer full.  This is an attempt to make sure that whatever audio it does write comes out continuously.  It is typically the case with audio drivers or servers (like pulseaudio) that audio is only written in chunks.  When you write less than a full chunk of data to the audio buffer, the card produces no sound, since the driver or the server is waiting for enough audio data so that it can write a full chunk at once.  Since the data that minimodem writes is generally not going to match full chunks of audio, you have a situation where the last part of the audio data won't get written.  To avoid this problem, minimodem writes enough silence to guarantee that the last part of the audio gets output to the card.

For example, let's say the audio driver or server writes in 1000 byte chunks.  Now let's say that you type one character, and that produces 2500 bytes of audio data.  The audio driver or server will cause 2000 bytes of data to be played and 500 bytes will be left in the buffer.  Since a modem protocol requires continuous audio, it doesn't make any sense to just leave those 500 bytes of audio data in the buffer.  The receiver wouldn't see a complete character.  The receiver would then have to assume tha audio was garbled and discard the character.

So, to avoid this, minimodem will write 0.5 seconds of silence, which is probably thousands of bytes of audio data.  This will guarantee that the 500 bytes of audio data that are left in the buffer get played, since there will certainly be enough audio data to finish out that chunk.

Now it is true that there will likely be some extra silence in the buffer, and that won't get played immediately, but that's not a big deal, since that won't cause any corruption.  The receiver can handle varying amounts of silence between the data (note that this specific to how minimodem works, a real model would always be generating sound).

Minimodem could be improved by having it set the chunk size manually.  This way, it would know exactly how much silence needs to be written to flush the audio instead of writing an arbitrary amount, so the delay could be reduced to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks heaps Vaughn. Could you point me to what file/line number this is functionality is found? I'm using ALSA not Portaudio if that helps. Thanks again.

Comment: I found it. I'll try to work something out. I just don't know where to start. Wish me luck. Thanks for the help.